# When did the UK stop using full stops in abbreviations and acronyms?

Tags: history, abbreviations, style-manuals

I have noticed that in older (usually over 30 or 40 years old) British books and newspapers, abbreviations are without exception typeset with in full stops, as is still the practice in the United States.  Yet, virtually without exception,  modern publications typeset all the abbreviations without full stops.  So, for example, in an old text one might see:

> Marshall Hall K.C. — U.K . — *Walsh v. Lonsdale* — James Maxwell
>   F.R.S.

Whereas  virtually all modern British publications would write:

> Marshall Hall KC — UK — *Walsh v Lonsdale* — James Maxwell
>   FRS

When and why did this change happen? As best I can tell, it was sometime in the 20th century, but I have yet to find details on the change in style.

Comment: i don't think anyone can give you a date; the trend towards lighter or 'open' punctuation is just that, a trend, whose start is not precisely  recorded, and which is still ongoing. There is no Ministry of Punctuation which issued a Statutory Instrument on April 1st, 1976. Personally for 'when',  I would say since the 1960s and accelerated by the widespread adoption of word-processing. As for 'why', I would point to a trend towards less 'busy' appearance of printed text, reduced typing, fewer 'rules', etc.

Comment: Liable for closure as opinion-based (in my opinion).

Comment: Why? That is a sociological question not a linguistic one. I could make suggestions, but they would just be opinions anyway. Doubly off-topic I'm afraid. And as for "when" — without wishing to be rude, why are you expecting others to do your research for you?

Comment: I am not sure your premise is correct.  To name a few:  The National Rifle Association uses NRA’ without stops.  I see AFC, NFL, FBI and could probably go on.  I think you should check again.

Comment: @Tuffy - the question specifically asks about UK/British practice, and all of your examples are, as far as I know, US abbreviations.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey As I understand it, the question presupposes that UK publishers have  ceased to use full stops in acronyms, whereas American publishers have retained the use of stops.  I am citing only American examples because I am pointing out that the claim about American practice is incorrect.  A notable exception is my spell-checker, which tries insist on stops even though it is set for British English!

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Harvey says, this is a trend, and indeed the [American Heritage Abbreviations Dictionary](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JUoGoSTUhTYC&pg=PP10) says so:

> Abbreviations vary widely in their style of punctuations, ...
>   Following the contemporary trend toward less frequent use of periods,
>   entries in *The American Heritage Abbreviations Dictionary*, Second
>   Edition, are generally shown without periods, except for truncations
>   and terms that require or almost always appear with punctuation.

This journal article from 1989 suggests that periods get dropped from abbreviations when they become commonly used as words:

> The fact that a given abbreviation or acronym is spelled more often
>   today without periods than with them suggests that it is now a more
>   direct part of the vocabulary.

From Cannon, G. (1989). Abbreviations and Acronyms in English Word-Formation. American Speech, 64(2), 99. doi:10.2307/455038 (page 11)

Note, therefore, that this trend is not necessarily restricted to the UK!

Comment: There is (or was) an expression which these days is rendered as 'A1 at Lloyds', which, of a ship insured at Lloyds of London, meant it was 'A' for hull condition and '1' for standard of fittings and trappings, that is, it was in the best possible state. I have seen an extract from the records of the US Congress (1870) that "The labor per ship of about one thousand tons classed **A 1**, at, Lloyds, will amount to ten dollars per ton. " Conversely, a British 1929 film was called "**A.1.** at Lloyds". So a date would be ridiculous.

Comment: The question asks "why" and "when" your answer addresses neither of these points.

Comment: 'Why'? The quote from the 1989 paper says why - these abbreviations have become a more direct part of the vocabulary.